# Detective unit tests on historical versions in source control

Tags: testing, version-control

Is there a tool to run unit tests on previous versions of software that's in source control?
The idea would be a bug surfaced and I want to know when it was introduced so I write a new test and the software checks out each back version from source control, running the test on each one, until the test doesn't fail anymore or we reach the beginning.

We use subversion but I'm curious of if anything like this exists in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial has a built in command called bisect that essentially does what you are looking for.

It is designed to work with a user-written script but in a nutshell, it does a binary search where your script (which runs the unit tests) tells bisect if the checked out revision "passes" or "fails" and based on that it moves through the history until it finds the revision where the bug was introduced.

I'm not sure if such a tool exists for SVN, but I've found bisect with Mercurial to be very useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Bisect in Mercurial (and Git) perform exactly this job, except of ckecking *each back version* - it finds source of problem faster

Answer (score 1):

Just about any version control system lets you check out a specific version of an entire build.  And lets you track the history/the changes of any specific file(s) of the build.

Normally, I just take a simple "divide and conquer" approach:

```
  a) Check out a really old version into a scratch directory

  b) Build and confirm it DOESN'T have the bug

  c) Manually compare the old and current versions and make "educated guesses" as to "what changed".

  d) Check out a version between the old and current version (based on what I found in step c).

  e) Build and test.

  f) If it has the bug, check out version between a) and d).

     If it doesn't have the bug, check out a version between d) and the current.

  g) Rinse and repeat
```

And yes, some or all of this can certainly be scripted.

In bash (if you're on Linux), or in the scripting language of your choice.